# How to avoid execution of Python UnitTest method "addCleanup" after test case failure?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following Python UnitTest:

```
import unittest

class SimpleTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "\nmessage from function: setUp"
        self.createResource()
        self.addCleanup(self.cleanResource)

    def createResource(self):
        print "\nmessage from function: createResource"

    def cleanResource(self):
        print "\nmessage from function: cleanResource"

    def test_func1(self):
        print "message from function: test_func1::start"
        print "message from function: test_func1::end"

    def test_func2(self):
        print "message from function: test_func2::start"

        self.assertTrue(False)

        print "message from function: test_func2::end"

    def test_func3(self):
        print "message from function: test_func3::start"
        print "message from function: test_func3:end"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

After the above code exution with option "-f" functions are executed in below order

```
python -m unittest -fb test_cases

message from function: setUp

message from function: createResource
message from function: test_func1::start
message from function: test_func1::end

message from function: cleanResource
.
message from function: setUp

message from function: createResource
message from function: test_func2::start
F
message from function: cleanResource

======================================================================
FAIL: test_func2 (test_cases.SimpleTestCases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cases.py", line 23, in test_func2
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

It will stop the execution after first failure but will call the **"addCleanup"** method.

I want to avoid to call **"addCleanup"** method when test function **"test_func2"** so the created resources can be used for debugging purpuse.

Is there any command-line option or workaround available?

Comment: AFAIK `doCleanup` will run no matter what. You can set some instance variable in your test and then check it's value on the cleanup functions. Not pretty but might work

Answer (score 1):

As one of the simplest ways - is just to put input (raw_input for Python 2) at the start of a cleanResource method.
So execution will be stopped until the Enter key pressed.

```
def cleanResource(self):
    temp = raw_input('wait before cleanResource')
    print("\nmessage from function: cleanResource")
```

Another way is to use breakpoint in the debugger

```
import pdb
```

and then

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

where needed

Comment: Yeah, it might be used as one time exception, just to debug the particular problem...
Not for use in working code, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As per unittest documentation [doCleanups()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.doCleanups) is the method responsible to call all the cleanup methods.

One way is to check the result of the test case in doCleanups method, if test case is failed then pop up all the cleanup methods and skip rest of the test cases

Below is the code:

```
import unittest

class SimpleTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    FAILURE = False

    def setUp(self):
        print "\nmessage from function: setUp"
        if SimpleTestCases.FAILURE:
            self.skipTest("Test is skipped due to first failure")

            return super(SimpleTestCases, self).setUp()

        self.createResource()
        self.addCleanup(self.cleanResource)

    def createResource(self):
        msg = "\nmessage from function: createResource"

    def cleanResource(self):
        print "\nmessage from function: cleanResource"

    def test_func1(self):
        print "message from function: test_func1::start"
        print "message from function: test_func1::end"

    def test_func2(self):
        print "message from function: test_func2::start"

        self.assertTrue(False)

        print "message from function: test_func2::end"

    def test_func3(self):
        print "message from function: test_func3::start"
        print "message from function: test_func3:end"

    def doCleanups(self):
        print "message from function: doCleanups"
        if SimpleTestCases.FAILURE:
            return super(SimpleTestCases, self).doCleanups()

        result = getattr(self, '_outcomeForDoCleanups', self._resultForDoCleanups)

        ok_result = True
        exc_list = getattr(result, 'failures')

        if exc_list and exc_list[-1][0] is self:
            ok_result = ok_result and not exc_list[-1][1]

        if not ok_result:
            SimpleTestCases.FAILURE = True
            while self._cleanups:
                (func, args, kwargs) = self._cleanups.pop()

        return super(SimpleTestCases, self).doCleanups()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = unittest.main()
```

Execute as

```
python -m unittest test_cases
```

And output:

```
message from function: setUp
message from function: test_func1::start
message from function: test_func1::end
message from function: doCleanups

message from function: cleanResource
.
message from function: setUp
message from function: test_func2::start
Fmessage from function: doCleanups

message from function: setUp
smessage from function: doCleanups

======================================================================
FAIL: test_func2 (test_cases.SimpleTestCases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cases.py", line 30, in test_func2
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1, skipped=1)
```